# How to make a unique column whose uniqueness depends on another column (enum values)? (ASP .NET Core)

Tags: c#, database, asp.net-core

I have a table like this:

```
public class Invoice
{
        [Key]
        public int Id { get; set; }
    
        public string Name {get; set} }

        public InvoiceType InvoiceType { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public string InvoiceNumber { get; set; }

        public string TaxIdentificationNumber { get; set; }
}
```

Invoice type enum:

```
public enum InvoiceType 
{
 Type0 = 0,
 Type1 = 1,
 Type2 = 2,
}
```

I have the following requirements:

- if it is a Type1 invoice, each InvoiceNumber must be unique.
- if it is a Type2 invoice, the InvoiceNumber cannot be repeated with the same TaxIdentificationNumber

I cannot separate the invoice types into a separate table. I have to keep each type of invoice in one main table.

How can I restrict table columns depending on the enum type?

Comment: you can create unique indexes https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/indexes?tabs=data-annotations

Answer (score 1):

At the first sight, you problem can be solved by a CHECK constraint or a filtered INDEX, which should be supported by many relational database engines. However looks like it's easier to do with [filtered INDEX](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/indexes?tabs=data-annotations#index-filter), which can be configured right in EFCore configuration. Something like this:

```
//for the first case
modelBuilder.Entity<Invoice>()
            .HasIndex(e => e.InvoiceNumber)
            .HasFilter("[InvoiceType]=1").IsUnique();

//for the second case
modelBuilder.Entity<Invoice>()
            .HasIndex(e => new { e.InvoiceNumber, e.TaxIdentificationNumber })
            .HasFilter("[InvoiceType]=2").IsUnique();
```

I suppose your `enum` value of `InvoiceType` is stored as `int` value in the database. Otherwise (stored as enum string), you just adjust the code accordingly.